Get Gmail Messages under the label without Threads using Google Apps Script
I receive order emails daily. Sometimes they are grouped in the same thread, and sometimes they are individual but belongs to the thread. They all go under the same label "InProcess", when I use firstLabel.getThreads() it only gets the emails which belong to the thread. Here is the sample script:
function processEmails() { 

  var firstLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('FromLabel');
  var secondLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('ToLabel');
  var threads = firstLabel.getThreads(); 


  if (threads.length > 0) {

    for (var i = threads.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var thread = threads[i];
      var messages = thread.getMessages(); // Get all messages in the thread

      for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
        var message = messages[j]; // Process each message in the thread
        var plainBody = message.getPlainBody();
        console.log(plainBody);

        //do the processing

       
      // Label the thread as processed and remove the original label
      thread.addLabel(secondLabel).refresh(); // Mark thread as processed
      thread.removeLabel(firstLabel).refresh(); // Remove the original label
    }
   }
  }
}

So, it either gets all the messages of the thread or no message if it is separated from the thread. For example in the below screenshot, script says that there is only one thread that has multiple messages, leaving the other 2 emails unprocessed (which are ungrouped/splitted from certain threads):

I want to just get these 3 messages/emails without considering the thread. Is there any query something like GmailApp.search('label:'+ ?) that we can use to get only messages. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Could you clarify what you mean by I want to just get these 3 messages/emails without considering the thread? Are you asking to retrieve all emails in a thread, excluding the main email? if not kindly enlighten us to what expected result you want.

sometimes Gmail groups the messages (new incoming emails) in the thread, sometimes the emails are splitted from the thread and behave as an individual message , I want to get this individual message regardless of the thread with which they are attached

Basically I want to get messages (individual emails) which are ungrouped/splitted from a thread and placed as an individual mails under a label

It seems like you want to separate individual emails (single emails) from emails with threads by assigning them different labels. If this is not the case, could you please clarify the expected result you're aiming for?

Lets say, there are 2 emails in one thread, if you split/ungroup them, they will become 2 separate emails however the limitation with the above script is it will not get them as 2 separate emails (individually), I want to get the ungrouped emails as they are shown in the above image. So ideally, script should return 3 emails regardless of the fact that they are ungrouped from threads. Hope it is clear now

I found a workaround to this from the following source, the script that gets only the messages and not threads is:
function listMessages () {
  // Only return messages matching the specified query.
  var msgs = Gmail.Users.Messages.list('me', {'q':'label:InProcess'}).messages;

  msgs.forEach(function (e){
   var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(e.id); // Fetch message by its ID
   var plainBody = message.getPlainBody();
  });

}


You can try this as a work-around
On the current stages, splitting threads is not supported by Google Apps Script. Although there are ways to do it, this is going to be more complicated and is actually being sold as add-ons by some development companies. On the other hand, I do have a workaround for you:
Create the email template
var emailSubject = `Fwd: ${subject} (From: ${from})`;
var emailBody = `This is a forwarded message from the thread:\n\n--- Original Message ---\nFrom: ${from}\n\n${body}`;

Send the email to yourself
 GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), emailSubject, emailBody);
        console.log(`Message sent: Subject - ${emailSubject}`);
      }

Move the original thread to the "ToLabel" after processing
  thread.addLabel(toLabel).refresh();
  thread.removeLabel(firstLabel).refresh(); 
}

Forwarded emails to the "ToLabel"
function myFunctions2(toLabel) {
  var now = new Date(); 
  var recentSentEmails = GmailApp.search(`from:${Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()} newer_than:1d`); 

  for (var i = 0; i < recentSentEmails.length; i++) {
    var thread = recentSentEmails[i];
    var messages = thread.getMessages();

    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var message = messages[j];
      if (message.getTo() === Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()) {
        thread.addLabel(toLabel).refresh();
        console.log(`Added "ToLabel" to forwarded message: ${message.getSubject()}`);
      }
    }
  }

Script used
function processAndSendEmails() {
  var firstLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('FromLabel');
  var toLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('ToLabel');
  var threads = firstLabel.getThreads(); 

  if (threads.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      var thread = threads[i];
      var messages = thread.getMessages(); 

      for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
        var message = messages[j];
        var subject = message.getSubject();
        var body = message.getPlainBody();
        var from = message.getFrom();
        
        var emailSubject = `Fwd: ${subject} (From: ${from})`;
        var emailBody = `This is a forwarded message from the thread:\n\n--- Original Message ---\nFrom: ${from}\n\n${body}`;


        GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), emailSubject, emailBody);
        console.log(`Message sent: Subject - ${emailSubject}`);
      }

      thread.addLabel(toLabel).refresh();
      thread.removeLabel(firstLabel).refresh(); 
    }

    myFunctions2(toLabel);
  }
}


function myFunctions2(toLabel) {
  var now = new Date(); 
  var recentSentEmails = GmailApp.search(`from:${Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()} newer_than:1d`); 

  for (var i = 0; i < recentSentEmails.length; i++) {
    var thread = recentSentEmails[i];
    var messages = thread.getMessages();

    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var message = messages[j];
      if (message.getTo() === Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()) {
        thread.addLabel(toLabel).refresh();
        console.log(`Added "ToLabel" to forwarded message: ${message.getSubject()}`);
      }
    }
  }
}

Note: The affected data on this work around would be the original Owner and Message ID
Sample Output
Labels

Email FromLabel

Validations

Receiving Emails that splitted

Reference

GmailApp

